# Call derived class method from base class instance without casting

Tags: c++, c++11

There is another way to call derived class method from a base pointer object without casting?

```
class Base
{
};

class Derived : public Base
{
    public:
    void set() {printf("bbbbbbbbbbbb"); }

};

int main()
{
  Base* pbBase;

  pbBase = new Derived();

  //pbBase->set(); // Compilation error.
  (Derived*)pbBase->set(); // Working.
}
```

Comment: But your "Working" code [doesn't](https://godbolt.org/z/YWpq8o) compile.

Comment: That's because it should be ((Derived*)pbBase)->set();

Comment: Declare `set()`as a virtual method

Comment: Are you learning "How not to do polymorphism in C++"?

Comment: Itay: Did you manage to do this without casting and without `virtual` methods? I noticed that the question is still open.

Answer (score 5):

You can add `virtual` methods in `Base` that you override in `Derived`.

Note that you should make the destructor `virtual` too or else the derived class' destructor would not get called when you `delete` the object through a base class pointer.

```
#include <iostream>

class Base
{
public:
    virtual ~Base() = default;
    virtual void set() = 0;    // = 0 makes it pure virtual
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    void set() override { std::cout << "bbbbbbbbbbbb\n"; }

};

int main()
{
  Base* pbBase;

  pbBase = new Derived();

  pbBase->set();

  delete pbBase;
}
```